# BeautifulSoup removing tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove the style tags and their contents from the source, but it's not working, no errors just simply doesn't decompose. This is what I have:

```
source = BeautifulSoup(open("page.html"))
getbody = source.find('body')
for child in getbody[0].children:
    try:
        if child.get('style') is not None and child.get('style') == "display:none":
            # it in here
            child.decompose()
    except:
        continue
print source
# display:hidden div's are still there.
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid; there is no `except` handler. If you are using `except: pass` *remove* the `try`/`except` altogether to see any bugs you are masking.

Comment: `getbody[0]` raises a `KeyError` as well.

Comment: I don't know how that code doesn't throw any `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what you want and works fine; do *not* use blanket except handling to mask bugs:

```
source = BeautifulSoup(open("page.html"))
for hidden in source.body.find_all(style='display:none'):
    hidden.decompose()
```

or better still, use a regular expression to cast the net a little wider:

```
import re

source = BeautifulSoup(open("page.html"))
for hidden in source.body.find_all(style=re.compile(r'display:\s*none')):
    hidden.decompose()
```

`Tag.children` only lists *direct* children of the `body` tag, not all nested children.