# remove hidden lines in html code using bs4 and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to remove the type="hidden" lines from html code that I've pulled through python. the reason for this is I'm extracting the form tag data from html code to create a dictionary eg:
{"username": "", "password": "", "Login": "submit"}
however, because beautifulsoup is extracting everything on the type="hidden" lines aswell my dictionary is looking pretty ridiculous and obviously completely unusable.
here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
import re

target_url = "https://example.com"


def request(url):
    try:
        return requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass


response = request(target_url)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
forms_list = parsed_html.find("form")
for hidden in forms_list.body.findAll(re.findall('(?:<input ")(.*?)>')):
    hidden.decompose()


for form in modified_form:
    action = form.get("action")
    post_url = urljoin(target_url, action)
    method = form.get("method")

    inputs_list = form.findAll("input")
    post_data = {}
    for input in inputs_list:
        input_name = input.get("name")
        input_type = input.get("type")
        input_value = input.get("value")
        post_data[input_name] = input_type
    result = requests.post(post_url, data=post_data)
    print(post_data)
```

I get this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "form.py", line 21, in 
for hidden in forms_list.body.findAll(re.findall('(?:<input ")(.*?)>')):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'body'

I'm very new to this so apologies if my code is appalling. how do i remove just the type="hidden" lines from the html code been parsed through beautifulsoup?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654698/beautifulsoup-removing-tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup removing tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654698/beautifulsoup-removing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to remove tags, just select all `<input>` tags that don't contain atribute `type="hidden"` (for example with CSS selector `input:not([type="hidden"])`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
    <form action="/some_action" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="value1" />

        <input type="text" id="u" name="username" value="username" />
        <input type="text" id="p" name="password" value="password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.form.select('input:not([type="hidden"])'):
    print(i.get('name'), i.get('type'), i.get('value'))
```

Prints:

```
username text username
password text password
None submit Submit
```

Comment: great bit of code, thank you very much for that. it worked a dream. however, I've tested it against a few websites now (on virtual machines such as metasploitable) and on some of them the data is pulled through wonderfully. but on others it fails to pick up certain data like the submit button type. and whenever i try to pull the action tag (i.get('action')) it always comes back as none. have any idea why?

Comment: @BILLYBOB `action=` parameter is inside the `<form>`, so you have to find the form tag and thed get the acion, for example: `soup.find('form').get('action')`

Comment: Okay great, thanks again Andrej. Just one last thing, I'm almost there, what is the best way to extract the "submit button" i can now pull all relevant data using all that you have put so far but i need to extract the line containing the data regarding the submit button. is there a simple CSS selector to do this?

Comment: @BILLYBOB The simplest way is just to delete the key from the dictionary you have...for example `del post_data['submit']` or similar

Comment: Apologies, i worded my question badly. what i ment was when running my updated code the .get('name') regarding the submit button isn't been found. when i do this for expmaple "form = parsed_html.form.select('input:not([type="hidden"])') print(form)" everythiong beginning with tag <input> is still there, however the the name/type for the login button isn't, this is because the line containing those details begins with a <button> tag. how do i keep this? bearing in mind that some websites may be different and the <button> tag might be labelled something else

Comment: @BILLYBOB Then you can make `if i.get('name') is None: continue` and it will not add this `None` data to your post data.